# File deletion detect from any folder of my operating system and prevent the deletion by c# or win32 api

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

i know we can monitor a particular folder with FileSystemWatcher. with the help of FileSystemWatcher we can save the log which file was deleted. suppose i have windows service which will run all the time and if any user try to delete any file from my OS with specific extension then control then my windows service will show a messge box to user and prevent the user to delete that file. i just want to know can i do this with FileSystemWatcher class. if it is possible with FileSystemWatcher then please discuss here how or if not possible with FileSystemWatcher then how could i make it possible with my win service or normal win apps. would it be possible by win32 api?? . thanks

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: @LukeHennerley If you don't know what's being asked about in the last 3 sentences, this doesn't mean there's no question there - it's just that you don't understand them.

Answer (score 2):

Use proper Windows security measures - File permissions together with access groups.

Comment: i want to do it programatically. how it will be possible programatically......can u discuss bit more about which api i need to use with c#.

Comment: It is probably not even possible to do it the way you envision.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to have a filesystem filter driver which will track deletion and movement request (movement to recycle bin here) and will cancel such requests. You can write your own filter driver or use our CallbackFilter product. With CallbackFilter the task is trivial - less than a dozen of lines of code in user-mode (possibly in C#).

Comment: what is filesystem filter driver?? r u trying to say use any 3rd party library. can u please give me some hints with code snippet as a result i can see what .net classes u r going to use.

Comment: @Thomas See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg462968.aspx for information about filter drivers. This is a kernel-mode driver, written in C (not even C++). As for our product, we have plenty information on our site (see my profile) and samples included with the evaluation version. Support is provided there as well.